# reset file input ajax error

Tags: php, html, ajax, archivo

Hola que tal he estado intentanto que en un formulario de mi web page el input de "file" se resete, agrego solo estos campos ya que los demás input que tengo en el formulario si se resetean, no se donde esta el error, solo no funciona en los "file". El primero script que tengo es para mostrar el nombre del archivo no creo que este sea el problema, el segundo script es el ajax que estoy usando supongo que ahí esta el error.

```
<div class="custom-file">
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" 
name="archivo2">
<label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile1"> Sticker </label>
</div>

 <script>
$(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
$(this).siblings(".custom-file- 
label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);});
```

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#frmajax').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var datos = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"php/db.php",
        data:datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(r){
            if(r==1){
                alert(" ");
            }else{
                alert("Agregado con exito");
                $("#frmajax")[0].reset();
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Los `input` tipo `file` suelen ser problemáticos en estos casos, para solucionarlo te recomiendo envolver el campo en una etiqueta `form`, ya que esta permite el reseteo de los `input` internos:

```
<form>
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="archivo2">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile1"> Sticker </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

El Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#frmajax').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var datos = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"php/db.php",
        data:datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(r){
            if(r==1){
                alert(" ");
            }else{
                alert("Agregado con exito");
                $("form")[0].reset();
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
   });
 });
```